# Call function in twig.js file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating an express application and for the views render I use `twig.js`.

I'm displaying some posts from mongodb into index.twig file. The question is **how can I call a function from a js file**(let's call it `Utils.js`) **in the `twig` file?**

My index.twig file looks something like this:

```
<div class="post-date">{{ post["date"] }}</div>
<div class="post-body">
    {{ post["body"] }}
</div>
```

What I need to do is to format that `post["date"]` calling a method from `Utils.js` not just echoing it out as it is. How can I do that ?

P.S. I know that there are filters for date but I want my own data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered here: https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js/issues/206#issuecomment-73443040

To add a filter you can use Twig.extendFilter():

```
Twig.extendFilter('foo', function (value) {
    return util.format(value);
});
```

After adding a filter you'll be able to use it in your templates:
`{{ value|foo }}`